# Finding column number of a matching cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find out the column numbers of the cell containing a matching string in VBA. I am using range find to do so. for example in sheet one I have following in sheet1

```
**Block Sub Block**
A       sfdbfg
B       hhd
sdsad   trh
adfasd  hrh
afadc   bdgfb
```

in Sheet2 I want to find the column numbers of column "Block" and "Sub Block" and then based on certain criteria I am trying read some rows from these columns. I am using following code-

```
Header1_column_num = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheet1).Range("A1:A5").Find("Block",LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

Header2_column_num = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheet1).Range("A1:A5").Find("Sub Block", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

but when I execute this code it throws an error on line Header2_column_num-
"object variable or with block variable not set"

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `Sheets("Sheet1")...` or just `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.Range(...)`?

Comment: `Range("A1:A5")` only has 1 column.

Comment: I dont know how to respond to a person's comment but this is in response to your comment Scott Carner... I dont have words for my stupidity. You saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean that you are trying to find the row number?

Comment: @Tom I was trying to find the column numbers but Scott rightly pointed out that I was passing wrong range. Range I passed had only one column. That's why it was failing. Thanks all for your support. Really appreciate.